# Java applet for file upload(no limit).direct upload from local dorectory to server

Tags: java, applet

I want to make a java applet, it will update all the files in my local directory to a web server. There is no limit for files. I am new to making applets.

I have no applet interface.

I have some files in my c drive those should be uploaded directly in to web server.

This should be done automatically.

Comment: "very urgent help me.." Saying urgent doesn't help unless there's a bounty on the post. In addition what have you *tried*?

Comment: "localhost:8090" "connect,resolve")created client side program which will connect the server.then i got

Answer (score 0):

Because of java applet security restrictions, it is impossible to read the local files, because you don't want an applet uploading sensitive information, do you? If you want this to work, you have to sign the applet, and users have to agree to run the signed applet and give it more permissions.